# Basic Codeigniter HMVC Installation

Tags: codeigniter, hmvc

I have a existing working installation of CI 2.02 that autoloads libraries and helpers. When I perform the HMVC installation by dropping the core and 3rd party files into their respective locations in the CI directory, I get the error

```
Fatal error: Cannot access empty property in C:\xampp\htdocs\APPNAME\application\third_party\MX\Loader.php on line 208
```

When I remove all helpers from application/config/autoload.php, i get

```
An Error Was Encountered
Unable to load the requested file: helpers/_helper.php
```

When I use a clean CI installation with no libraries or helpers autoloading, it works fine. What should I do to get HMVC and autoloading to work?

I installed HMVC by following the instructions on their website (https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc/wiki/Home). I only did Step 15 and doing Step 6 shows the error I mentioned earlier. I have a single controller file in /application/controllers, a single model file in /application/models and a single view file in /application/views which I move to /application/modules/site/controllers, /application/modules/site/models and /application/modules/site/views respectively. I left the config.php, autoload.php anad database.php as they are in the application folder.

Before installing HMVC (performing Steps 1-6 from their website), I already have a existing CI project. I am autoloading some libraries and helpers (database, session, file, url, forms, text) using application/config/autoload.php.

Is there any more info that I need to show to figure out where the problem lies in? This is my first CI project so its nothing fancy. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade to 2.0.3 and the latest version of HMVC, it should work fine.